# Publishing multiple sites on a single instance of umbraco

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, sites, hostheaders

I am looking to setup a parallel site to one already that already uses umbraco for its content management system.  The new site would share admins, templates, macros, and media resources, but not any content.  If I setup multiple host headers pointing to the same directory with an umbraco install, how can I switch the top node (home vs home2) of the site based on which url is being accessed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you first have to change a setting in umbracosettings.config:

```
<useDomainPrefixes>true</useDomainPrefixes>
```

Then I think you also have to right click on each top node and click 'Manage Hostnames', then add the appropriate host name for that top node.

It already sounds like you have IIS configured correctly, so you should be good to go on that front.

It's been a while since I've worked with Umbraco, but I think I'm mostly right ;-)

Comment: If you change this setting you may need to restart IIS for it to take effect - I did