# Orchard - single admin interface for multiple sites. Is this possible

Tags: orchardcms

I need to setup an Orchard install for a single client with multiple domains, so the multi tenancy module http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-Orchard-site does not seem to apply. Each domain has separate content, but they would like to share images and other media and have the same user maintain the sites from a single login in a single admin interface. I can see that Umbraco supports this [Publishing multiple sites on a single instance of umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049/publishing-multiple-sites-on-a-single-instance-of-umbraco) But in Orchard, is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think multi-tenancy wouldn't work? Is it just the media? If so, you'd just need to let tenants peek one level up above their own media folder. Shouldn't be too hard although you won't get it out of the box.

Comment: would that not also fail on the single login requirement? Would they need to login to one then out and into the other to make multiple changes?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "maintain the sites". But yes, or you'd have to implement an authentication replacement that makes the users common across tenants.