# How to host multiple website in already Hosted Umraco in local IIS

Tags: umbraco7

I'm new to Umraco CMS i'm developed a site and hosted in local IIS, but i have One More site and  i want to hosted in Umbraco How to Host Multiple sites in single Umbraco.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publishing multiple sites on a single instance of umbraco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049/publishing-multiple-sites-on-a-single-instance-of-umbraco)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have one instance of Umbraco for each website.  However, there are exceptions to this; for example multi-lingual websites or if your websites are so similar that they will share content, document types, templates etc. then you could  set up multiple websites in the same instance... it is relatively simple...

First of all you need to setup/bind your URLs to the Umbraco website in IIS. Go to Bindings in IIS for your Umbraco website and add the other URL.

As a simple example, in Umbraco, a website has a Home node at root level.  The children of that node are the pages on the site.

You can create another node at root level and create another site under that.

To set up a different URL for each root level node you just right-click each Home node and choose *Culture and Hostnames*.  Add the URL and language of your site. Done!

The URLs that you set up in IIS all point to the same Umbraco instance and Umbraco looks after the routing.

That's how it's done but honestly, if you have two totally unrelated sites, then you should have a separate instance of Umbraco for each.